# Derive correlation coefficient between two dependent variables in terms of correlation coefficient of independent variables

Tags: statistics, regression, correlation

I have following two equations:

θ<sub>t,s</sub><sup>obs</sup> = a<sub>s</sub>X<sub>t,s</sub><sup>obs</sup> + b<sub>s</sub>           ....................(1)

θ<sub>t,s</sub><sup>sim</sup> = a<sub>s</sub>X<sub>t,s</sub><sup>sim</sup> + b<sub>s</sub> ...................(2)

where t is time and s represent sites (I have data (time series) at 40 different sites). a and b vary only in space.

Here my question is that can we derive relationship correlation(θ<sub>t,s</sub><sup>obs</sup>, θ<sub>t,s</sub><sup>sim</sup>) in terms of correlation(a<sub>s</sub>, s=1,2,....40), correlation(X<sub>t,s</sub><sup>obs</sup>, X<sub>t,s</sub><sup>sim</sup>), and correlation(b<sub>s</sub>, s=1,2,....40)?